# Paragraphs not separating

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a blog, and every time I compose an article consisting of more than one paragraphs, it gets cluttered up altogether and it's all in the same paragraph.

Here's the code I wrote in my main page ejs for displaying the article content:

```
<% pos.forEach(function(post) { %>
<h3><u><%= post.title %></u></h3>
<p><%= post.post.substring(0, 101) + "..." %>
  <a href="/post/<%= post.title %>">Read More</a>
</p>
<% }); %>
```

Here's the code I wrote for my post ejs page:

```
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>

<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p><%= content %></p>

<%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your content consist of line break. You can use `<pre>` to render those lines

```
<pre><%= content %></pre>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

> Text in a  element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and the
> text preserves both spaces and line breaks. The text will be displayed
> exactly as written in the HTML source code.

Comment: The <pre> tag is making it look awkward. It does separate my paragraph but it makes my sentence jumbo and the user has to scroll to on the x axis to read the whole sentence. @Someone Special

Comment: You need to style it - https://css-tricks.com/considerations-styling-pre-tag/